# prove this beautiful relation $ det(A^{*}_{m,n})=per(A_{m,n})$ .

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

suppose $P_n$ and $P_m$ are paths with $n$ and $m$ edges respectively.consider $A_n$ and $A_m$ as adjacency matrix of them.now I want to calculate the number of perfect matching of $P_n \square P_m$ (it is cartesian product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs )

now I consider $A_{m,n}=A_m \otimes I_n + I_m \otimes A_n$ which is adjacency matrix for $P_n \square P_m$. ($\otimes$ is Kronecker product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

now because $P_n \square P_m$ is bipartite graph then the number of perfect matching is equal to $\sqrt{per(A_{m,n})}$.

now I know that if I define $A^{*}_{m,n}=A_m \otimes I_n + iI_m \otimes A_n$ which $i^2=-1$ it is enough to show that $ det(A^{*}_{m,n})=per(A_{m,n})$

my problem is to show this later equation which is so great relation.

please give me the way to prove that,any help will be great,thanks.

Comment: see http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/SLIDE/pfaforicm.pdf

Comment: To answer the question in the last part : No, it is not the right place. This forum is about math and not about begging. But the mathematical part is very interesting indeed.

Comment: so I delete it,thanks!

Comment: I must add that indeed I have so eager to prove the relation,thanks to  Chris Godsil because of great pdf but I couldn't find some hint about relation.